How to append some static content within a single cell of an existing CSV file
Let's assume I need to append the below content within the first cell (not be row by row) of the existing CSV file which has details of the customer. How can I achieve it?
Content to be added:
"This is Loganayaki ,she is trying to append the csv file

But she is not able to, she is facing difficulty using shell script

she is seeking help to fix this issue, so that she cab complete her task.
she tried few things which is not helping her"

Customer_File:
ID,Customer_Name,Cust_ADD
1,A,CBE
2,B,POL
3,C,POL

I tried the below code
#!/bin/bash

# File paths

csv_file="data.csv"

# New content to prepend

new_content="This is Loganayaki ,she is trying to append the csv file

But she is not able to, she is facing difficulty using shell script

she is seeking help to fix this issue, so that she cab complete her task.
she tried few things which is not helping her"

# Read existing content of the CSV file (excluding the first line)

existing_content=$(tail -n +2 "$csv_file")

# Combine new content with existing content

combined_content="$new_content"$'\n'"$existing_content"

# Write the combined content back to the CSV file

echo "$combined_content" > "$csv_file"

It is appending but the new_content is getting appended in three different rows and \n is coming as an empty row.
My expectation is
    This is Loganayaki ,she is trying to append the csv file
    
    But she is not able to, she is facing difficulty using shell script
    
    she is seeking help to fix this issue, so that she cab complete her task.
    she tried few things which is not helping her
    
   
   
   ID,Customer_Name,Cust_ADD
    1,A,CBE
    2,B,POL
    3,C,POL


is there is any link ,i can refer to

I mean...there's the link I provided in my previous comment.

Just to clarify, you just want to append the string in the first lines of the csv file? From the expected output, it seems to be the case

I think you can achieve the expected output by replacing tail -n +2 "$csv_file" with just cat "$csv_file" instead which would give combined_content="$new_content"$'\n\n\n'$(cat "$csv_file")

Thats right i want the append the string within first cell itself of the csv file

@larsks FYI some awk variants (e.g. GNU and Kernighans awk) have CSV parsing built in, see whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk, but the OPs question actually appears to have nothing to do with CSV, it's just about sticking the contents of a variable at the top of a file (which happens to be CSV but could be anything else).

Just enclose your $new_content in "double qoutes" as your string don't use one. Try simply: { printf '"%s"\n" "$new_content";cat "$csvFile";} >outfile.csv or printf '"%s"\n%s\n' "$new_content" "$(<$csvFile)" >outfile.csv....

I think the question is messed up a bit, not the least because what you write as expected content does not match the verbal description of what you want to achieve. My recommendation would be that you sit down and first think how the resulting file really should look like, and then ask a new question.

... Or more reusable: printf '"%s"\n%s\n' "${new_content//\"/\"\"}" "$(<$csvFile)" >outfile.csv;.

Don't try to read your whole input file into memory, just use a temp file:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) &&
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT &&
{
    printf '%s' "$new_content" &&
    cat -- "$csv_file"
} > "$tmp" &&
mv -- "$tmp" "$csv_file"

The &&s are necessary to avoid trashing your input file if anything fails in a previous step. If you're concerned about preserving permissions, etc. of the original file then change mv -- "$tmp" "$csv_file" to cat -- "$tmp" > "$csv_file".

I think if it's just appending to the first lines of the csv file, you just need to replace existing_content=$(tail -n +2 "$csv_file") with existing_content=$(cat "$csv_file") as you want to keep all original contents of the file
#!/bin/bash

# File paths

csv_file="data.csv"

# New content to prepend

new_content="This is Loganayaki ,she is trying to append the csv file

But she is not able to, she is facing difficulty using shell script

she is seeking help to fix this issue, so that she cab complete her task.
she tried few things which is not helping her"

# Read existing content of the CSV file (excluding the first line)

existing_content=$(cat "$csv_file")

# Combine new content with existing content

combined_content="$new_content"$'\n\n\n'"$existing_content"

# Write the combined content back to the CSV file

echo "$combined_content" > "$csv_file"

This would edit the file to be
This is Loganayaki ,she is trying to append the csv file

But she is not able to, she is facing difficulty using shell script

she is seeking help to fix this issue, so that she cab complete her task.
she tried few things which is not helping her


ID,Customer_Name,Cust_ADD
1,A,CBE
2,B,POL
3,C,POL


That is not valid CSV output, though

@tripleee : The resulting file is not supposed to be valid CSV anymore. Look at the expected output, as stated in the question.

As noted in comments, your expected output disagrees with your prose description of what you want. I surmise that this is due to a limited understanding of the CSV format; and so I'll propose a few alternative solutions which achieve what I assume you actually want.
As a brief background, for a text file to be a valid CSV file, it has to fulfill a couple of simple constraints.

Every record should contain the same number of fields (where typically a line is a record; but because a field can contain newlines, that's not strictly true)
Any field which contains a literal quote character, newline character, or separator needs to be quoted. (The separator is comma , by definition, but there are many common variations like TSV where the separator is a tab character instead, as well as semicolon-delimited, pipe-delimited etc variants.) Other fields may be quoted as well, but it's completely optional. To encode a literal separator character inside a quoted field, double it.

There are dialects with slightly different rules, but these are by far the most common conventions.
So, then, to append this multi-line value to a field, you need to quote it; and you need to maintain the existing field structure.
(To simplify the following exposition, I'll use a shorter value than the one you want. We will add the field
foo, "bar"
baz!

You'll notice that it contains a literal comma, literal quotes, and a literal newline.)
To append this value to the first non-header cell, the file would need to look like this:
ID,Customer_Name,Cust_ADD
"1foo, ""bar""
baz!",A,CBE
2,B,POL
3,C,POL

If you wanted to replace, not append, obviously take out the 1 which was the old value of this cell. To append (or replace) the first field name on the header line, it should be obvious what to change (i.e. target the first line instead of the second).
The challenge, then, is to apply the necessary modifications to the value before manipulating the file.
#!/bin/bash

csv_file="data.csv"

new_content="This is Loganayaki ,she is trying to append the csv file

But she is not able to, she is facing difficulty using shell script

she is seeking help to fix this issue, so that she cab complete her task.
she tried few things which is not helping her"

# Apply necessary transformations
replacement=${new_content//\"/\"\"}
replacement=${replacement//$'\n'/$'\\\n'}

# Replace
sed -i "2s/\([^,]*\),/\"\1$replacement\",/" "$csv_file"

The simple sed script replaces the first field and the comma after it on the second line with an opening quote, the previous value (\1), the new text, a closing quote, and a comma, effectively appending the new text to the existing value in the first cell on that line.
If you want to replace instead of append, you can omit the backreference to capture the previous value of the field.
sed -i "2s/^[^,]*,/$replacement,/" "$csv_file"

And, as noted above, if you want to target a different line than the second, change the line number address 2.
Demo: https://ideone.com/5o54dE
This is quite brittle, because

It will break if the replacement text contains a literal slash. You could change the sed script to use a different delimiter, or perform another transformation to add a backslash before every literal slash. Actually, you need to do that for every literal backslash or ampersand, too.
replacement=${replacement//[\\\/&]/\\&}

This uses a Bash parameter expansion which isn't portable to sh (whereas your original script didn't use any Bash syntax, and thus could well have had a #!/bin/sh shebang. Perhaps see also Difference between sh and bash)
You'll notice that we already employ something similar to backslash-escape each literal newline for sed. The above substitution will need to be performed before the one which adds backslashes before newlines.

It could break in peculiar ways if the existing field is already quoted. It wouldn't be hard to write a slightly different regex to handle that. (Like, permit a closing quote just before the comma, and omit the beginning quote from the new value in this case. The regex should permit double double quotes, or any characters which are not double quotes, in the first field. If you want to handle both possibilities, the script needs to be slightly more complex, though not by much.)


Some of the ugliness above stems from the unfortunate interface boundary between the shell and sed. You frequently see sed scripts be assembled from shell string variables, but this leads to many problems where you need to massage the strings in various ways to make them suitable for sed. With that in mind, a much cleaner interface is available to Awk scripts; but standard Awk does not have the convenient in-place editing of sed -i (which isn't standard either, but quite common). Then you simply need to write to a temporary file and rename it to replace the input file. Also, the Awk syntax is more verbose (but also then less write-only).
t=$(mktemp -t replace.XXXXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$t"; exit' ERR EXIT HUP INT
awk -F , -v replace="$new_content" '
BEGIN { OFS=FS; gsub(/"/, "\"\"", replace) }
FNR==2 { $1 = "\"" $1 replace "\"" } 1' "$csv_file" >"$t" &&
mv "$t" "$csv_file"

Demo: https://ideone.com/DoPH8x
This will require more extensive refactoring to correctly cope with quoted fields in the input.
At that point, though, rather than complicate the sed or Awk script, perhaps turn to Python, whose csv module handles all of this and much more for you.
import csv
import sys
 
 
csv_file="data.csv"
 
new_content = """This is Loganayaki ,she is trying to append the csv file
 
But she is not able to, she is facing difficulty using shell script
 
she is seeking help to fix this issue, so that she cab complete her task.
she tried few things which is not helping her"""
 
with open(csv_file) as inp:
    rows = csv.reader(inp)
    writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
    for lineno, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
        if lineno == 2:
            row[0] += new_content
        writer.writerow(row)

Demo: https://ideone.com/dSp7DK

The result you describe in "My expectation is ..." could be achieved with
if tf=$(mktemp)
then
  printf %s "$new_content" >$tf
  cat "$csv_file" >>$tf
  mv -- "$tf" "$csv_file"
fi

Or - adapting an idea by @EdMorton:
if tf=$(mktemp)
then
  {
    printf %s "$new_content"
    cat "$csv_file"
  } >$tf
  mv -- "$tf" "$csv_file"
fi

Of course the CSV file wouldn't be valid CSV anymore, as @tripleee mentioned in his comment, but this is what you have asked for.
